# Bootstrap JQuery SubMenu Navigation Hide/Show

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

All,

I built a working horizontal navigation, with submenus based off of the following example: [Horizontal Menu Hide/Show](http://www.bootply.com/WjsCLRE3d6)

Everything was working great as a standalone website, however, I'm integrating this into a content management system and for some reason, the JQuery must have a confliction.

When a link is clicked, the sub nav will appear, however, if you click on another navigation link, it will open the other submenu, but it will not close the previous submenu.

Does anyone know a way to rewrite the JQuery so that it essentially does the same thing? I'm hoping that I can simply change the script instead of coming up with an completely different method.

UPDATE: I discovered that the CMS system that I am placing my code into is running JQuery 1.8.2, where my program was running fine with JQuery 2.x.  I just created a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbxxfksg/) that uses this version of JQuery and now you can see what is happening. I cannot upgrade JQuery in the system, so I need to somehow make my code work inside of the older version. Please Assist.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        $('.collapse').not(this).removeClass('in');
    });

 $('[data-toggle=collapse]').click(function (e) {
     $('[data-toggle=collapse]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
     $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('active');
 });

$('li a').click(function(){
$(this).next('ul').slideToggle('500');
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle')
});
```

Comment: If you're conflicting with another library, have you looked at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: what if you put more specific classes or ids of those nav elements and targeted those instead?  I would guess the problem involves the general targeting of the elements.

Comment: I've tried using the noConflict functionality but have not had any luck. When I inspect the code with Chome Developer Tools, I can see it change the style to "display:block" but it will toggle that code off when another is clicked.

Comment: When the program is completed, the navigation will be dynamic and populated based off of a database, so if I were to use specific IDs and classes, they would need to be dynamic as well.

Comment: need a live example

Comment: The example is in the main question. I cannot get you into the CMS system as its not public. Hopefully, there's other ways out there to hide/show the subnavs and toggle between them.

Comment: UPDATE:  All, I discovered that the version that the CMS system is using of JQuery is 1.8.2.  I just created a JsFiddle using this version and you can see the results of whats happening.. I somehow need to get the hide/show feature of the sub menus to work properly with this version as I cannot upgrade to a newer version of JQuery.  https://jsfiddle.net/rbxxfksg/